# Unable to load image using imread()

Tags: python, opencv, image-loading

I am not sure of why this is happening but I am not able to load image using imread(). I am able to open that image in paint and after saving that image, the image is being loaded and displayed. I am using Jupyter notebook.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def displayImage(image):
 plt.imshow(image)
 plt.show()

image = cv2.imread('path/to/image')
displayImage(image)
```

Output

[image: Output]

Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: the links for the photo do not work for me. I only see a black screen

Comment: Why are you displaying OpenCV images with matplotlib? Use `cv2.imshow()` instead.

Comment: @zindarod, cv2 returns a numpy array, matplotlib is a perfectly good image display and avoids some of the problems with imshow

Comment: @MartinBeckett OpenCV reads images as BGR while matplotlib reads them as RGB. That's the problem with OP's code.

Comment: @zindarod Actually there is nothing in the Red, Green or Blue channels :-) See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because your image is in `RGBA` mode (your background is transparent). 
so you need to read your image in `RGBA` mode as:

```
image = cv2.imread('path/to/image.png',-1)
```

or:

```
from scipy.ndimage import imread
rgba = imread('path/to/image.png', mode='RGBA')
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Salman. I am able to read image using your solution.

Comment: I apologise for my comment - I really didn't mean anything in a nasty way. I have withdrawn it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your image doesn't contain any non-zero Red, Green or Blue pixels, it is entirely black. The only reason it looks how you show it with `"@ @ 6 L"` is because it has a an alpha/transparency channel that masks the black out and reveals the white PNG background colour.

If you look at it with ImageMagick's `identify` you will see:

```
identify -verbose a.png | more
Image: a.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 203x50+0+0
  Resolution: 37.79x37.79
  Print size: 5.37179x1.3231
  Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: Bilevel
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianess: Undefined
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Red: 1-bit
    Green: 1-bit
    Blue: 1-bit
    Alpha: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 10150
    Red:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 0 (0)                 <--- Brightest Red is zero
      mean: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: -3
      skewness: 0
      entropy: 0
    Green:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 0 (0)                 <--- Brightest Green is zero
      mean: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: -3
      skewness: 0
      entropy: 0
    Blue:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 0 (0)                  <--- Brightest Blue is zero
      mean: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: -3
      skewness: 0
      entropy: 0
    Alpha:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)                         <--- Alpha channel is only one with info
      mean: 16.477 (0.0646159)
      standard deviation: 58.73 (0.230314)
      kurtosis: 10.7342
      skewness: 3.50997
      entropy: 0.128008
   ...
   ...
   Background color: white       <--- Background is white
   ...
   ...
```

The answer is to read ALL FOUR channels with `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`, and just use the 4th/alpha channel:

```
def read_transparent_png(filename):
image_4channel = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
alpha_channel = image_4channel[:,:,3]
rgb_channels = image_4channel[:,:,:3]
```

Code extracted from [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/afternoon-debugging-e-commerce-image-processing-nikhil-rasiwasia/).

Comment: Sorry Mark, I didn't see your answer, but I think it's not a good manner to blame others copying your answers

Answer (score 0):

andCheck what data is actually being loaded.  Check the size with image.shape(), either look at the max/min/mean values or if you use spyder (highly recommended), look at the data in the variables viewer.

ps. for a single display item there is no need for the `plt.show()` command

Answer (score 0):

After loading the image use that:

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```